# Reset Password Email Template Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, passwords

I have Requirement to change the reset password email template, i have checked the woocommerece email settings and it is on for the reset email from there, but issue is when user request to reset the password it is generating email from there, but using the email content form Wordpress core File

```
wp-include > user.php
```

attached it is the screenshot as well.

[image]

What i have to do it to remove following section

Regards,
All at ###SITENAME###

So how i can achieve it and if there is any possibilities to enable the Woocommerece template somehow so can directly copy template in my child theme and customize it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `password_change_email` filter for customizing text.

```
add_filter( 'password_change_email', 'change_password_mail_message', 10, 3 );
function change_password_mail_message( 
  $pass_change_mail, 
  $user, 
  $userdata 
) {
  $new_message_txt = __( 'Your Text' );
  $pass_change_mail[ 'message' ] = $new_message_txt;
  return $pass_change_mail;
}
```